# Excel VBA - Dynamic PivotItems

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Is it able to get PivotItems number based on **Selection/ActiveCell location**?

EG: PivotTabel.RowFields(1).PivotItems(**x**)

I would want to get **x** based on **Selection/ActiveCell** within the PivotItems location **(Dynamic PivotItems)**.

Thanks

Comment: it is possible, but you need to give more data, `PivotTable` Name, `PivotField` name, `PivotItem`, which cell are you looking for (instead of using `ActiveCell` which is not recommended) . Also upload your latest code attempt

Comment: @Shai Rado....It's Okay...I solved it using the other method `ActiveCell.PivotCell.RowItems.Item(ActiveCell.PivotCell.RowItems.Count)`....Thanks for Helping